# power analysis for interaction of three within-subject factors

Tags: r, repeated-measures, statistical-power

I am trying to find an example of power analysis for an interaction effect of three within-subject factors (each factor has 2 levels).
I found only an example for an r code simulation with 2 factors, and unfortunately did not succeed in adapting it to the situation of 3 factors.

Does anyone know an example of such a power analysis?

Thank you very much

Comment: This will be easier using simulations.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I agree, and would love to perform such a simulation. However, as I am not that strong in data simulation, I am trying to find an example to learn from. Do you have an idea for such an example?

Comment: Even with simulations it's not that easy. Have a look at some other questions on this site regarding power analysis, for ex. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21237/calculating-statistical-power/21243#21243